# how to access variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm hoping there is a straightforward solution to this one. I'm simply trying to get the 'net_price', from my append, to use in another function.

Can anyone help at all?

JSON

```
$.getJSON("{{{ url('api/get-price')}}}", { id: $productId },
function(data){
    if(data.prices == true){
        $('#prices span').empty();
        $('#prices').fadeIn(2000);
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
            $('.cost').append('<div>Cost: ' + value.net_price +'</div>');
        });
    }
});
```

Function where I need to replace `XXXX` with price:

```
var calc = function(currentPrice){
     if(currentPrice.getPrice()==100){  
                this.setOptions({
                    maxPrice:'XXXXX'
     });
};
```

Comment: Is `calc` called immediately after the `get` call? If not, just store the price in a global variable.

Comment: Call `calc()` from the callback function.

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us what the structure of `data` is. Right now we can only guess as to what is going on here. Also, it is unclear how the `calc` function is called, what `currentPrice` is, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a global variable for the net price and then update the variable within your JSON call.

```
// Declare variable globally
var netPrice = '';

$.getJSON("{{{ url('api/get-price')}}}", { id: $productId },
function(data){

    // Update variable 
    netPrice = value.net_price;

    if(data.prices == true){
        $('#prices span').empty();
        $('#prices').fadeIn(2000);
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
            $('.cost').append('<div>Cost: ' + netPrice +'</div>');
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
    $('.cost').append('<div>Cost: <span class="netPrice">' + value.net_price +'</span></div>');
});
```

and access it from `calc` function:

```
var calc = function(currentPrice){
  if(currentPrice.getPrice()==100){  // if Saturday
      this.setOptions({
          maxPrice: $('.cost').find('.netPrice').text()
     });
   };
}
```

Comment: I tried this method, and am sure it will work, however it seems to only work if it is wrapped with apostrophes, as a string.  How best can I achieve that?